# How to save custom theme settings in a subtheme?

Tags: 7

I've created a subtheme of the [Premium Responsive](https://drupal.org/project/responsive) theme. It was working fine until I tried to change some of the [advanced theme settings](https://drupal.org/node/177868) within the subtheme's *Appearance* page. The parent theme adds settings for configuring social icons, a slideshow, etc., but unchecking some of the custom options and submiting the form resulted in a message saying "The configuration options have been saved", but the settings were returned to checked.

At first, I thought I needed to copy the theme-settings.php to my subtheme and customize it, but that results in two sets of settings displaying on the *Appearance* page, one for the parent theme and one for the subtheme (plus, still neither set of settings would stay unchecked when I submitted the form). This seems odd, since the [Creating a sub-theme](https://drupal.org/node/225125) documentation, says "Theme settings set via advanced theme settings' theme-settings.php are not inherited."

So, how am I supposed to set custom theme settings within a subtheme? Do I need to implement a theme-settings.php file within the subtheme or not?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. After doing an analysis I found the following:

1. THEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter is called for the base theme and then for the sub theme. It's not really a hook as they say - "Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().".
2. The base theme uses things like theme_get_setting('asdf_asdf', 'responsive') to get the default values for the settings form.
3. The settings you're saving are saved for the sub theme.
4. In templates settings are returned also using theme_get_setting('asdf_asdf', 'responsive').

Because of #2 and #3 the settings appear to not be saved.

Maybe they should have used theme_get_setting('asdf_asdf'). So it will default to the current theme. It can be used in both cases: #2 and #4. It would have worked fine.

For the sake of not altering the theme and because of #4, I would remove the extra settings in SUB_THEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter so you can modify the settings only in the base theme configuration page.

Comment: I posted an issue for this: https://drupal.org/node/2159683

Comment: Thanks - This can also be applied to any sub-theme you are creating where the parent has theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the module [magic](https://www.drupal.org/project/magic) although it's not always exporting the correct code. In any case it provides a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your current theme variable set as parent theme variable

```
$theme_subtheme_settings = variable_get('theme_subtheme_settings', array());   
if(empty($theme_oswsubtheme_settings)){
    $theme_parent_settings = variable_get('theme_parent_settings', array());
    variable_set('theme_subtheme_settings', $theme_parent_settings); 
  }
```